# Is it possible to set boundaries to the color mapping in Geopandas?

Tags: python, colors, geopandas

I'm using Geopandas.plot to plot the world and mapping each state with a int variable. I would like to know if is possible to still use the int variable to map the color and setting boundaries for the color spectrum. To be more clear, let assume I have 2 countries, the first one has in the int variable the value 2 and the second 5. The option column in the geopandas.plot() function will create a mapping in which the boundary are 5 and 2, is it possible to specifying that the boundaries are, for example, 0 and 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to specify `vmin` and `vmax`.

```py
gdf.plot('variable', vmin=0, vmax=10)
```